# Fedora 23 - Dual monitor Issue - Unwanted Mirroring

Tags: multiple-monitors, fedora, amd-radeon

I cannot get my dual Asus monitors not to mirror, when using Fedora 23. 
I had been using them without issue (screen sharing) on another HD with Kali, and also another HD with Windows 10. It's the same hardware.

From 'lspci' [AMD/ATI] Cypress LE [Radeon HD 5830] is my graphics card.

2nd monitor doesn't appear in the display/monitor settings.

I have unsuccessfully tried to install graphic drivers previously and it ended up causing issue when booting and the system would go blank/black screen part way through the Fedora loading bar screen - and not respond.

1 out of about 20 reboots, I could actually get into the log in screen.

Although, This is a fresh install - no such drivers installed as yet.

Any help would be appreciated - I am a Linux novice FYI.

Cheers

Comment: Does "mirroring" mean the exact same image appears on both monitors?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. Where as I wish to have screen sharing - Eg: A browser open in the left monitor and working in Text Editor in the right monitor.

Comment: I'd try searching for how to install the ATI/Radeon drivers for Fedora. I've seen guides for Ubuntu & Debian, so fedora's *should* exist, and I'll bet they involve text-only methods too for just in case the GUI doesn't keep going